# Spring batch: How to split and process the CSV file processing?

Tags: hibernate, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application that uses Azure SQL server as a backend, I am using Hibernate to update the database.

I am reading the data from CSV file using FlatfileReader & writing into Azure SQL Server using ItemWriter as mentioned below

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "STUDENTS")
    public class Student implements Serializable {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="student_sequence")
        @SequenceGenerator(name="student_sequence",sequenceName="student_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
        @Column(name="STUDENT_ID", unique = true)
        private Long studentId;
    
        @Column(name = "STUDENT_NAME")
        private String studentName;
    
        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        @Column(name = "ENROLLED_DATE")
        private Date enrolledDate;
    
        public String getStudentName() {
            return studentName;
        }
    
        public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
            this.studentName = studentName;
        }
    
        public Date getEnrolledDate() {
            return enrolledDate;
        }
    
        public void setEnrolledDate(Date enrolledDate) {
            this.enrolledDate = enrolledDate;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Student [studentId=" + studentId + ", studentName=" + studentName + ", enrolledDate=" + enrolledDate
                    + "]";
        }
    }
```

[image]

```
public class StudentMapper implements FieldSetMapper<Student> {

    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    
    @Override
    public Student mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
        
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setStudentName(fieldSet.readString(0));
        student.setEnrolledDate(new Date());

        return student;
    }

}
```

[image]

```
public class Reader implements ItemReader<FlatFileItemReader<Student>> {

    @Override
    public FlatFileItemReader<Student> read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        // Data Sources
        Resource inputCsv = new ClassPathResource("demo01/input/record.csv");

        // Spring Batch's built-in reader
        FlatFileItemReader<Student> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Student>();
        DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        String[] tokens = {"studentname"};
        tokenizer.setNames(tokens);
        reader.setResource(inputCsv);
        DefaultLineMapper<Student> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<Student>();
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new StudentMapper());
        reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
        return reader;
    }
}
```

[image]

```
public class Processor implements ItemProcessor<Student, Student> {

    @Override
    public Student process(Student item) throws Exception {
        
        System.out.println("Processing..." + item);
        return item;
    }

}
```

[image]

```
public class Writer implements ItemWriter<Student> {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Student> list) throws Exception {
        HibernateItemWriter<Student> hibernateItemWriter = new HibernateItemWriter<Student>();
        hibernateItemWriter.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        hibernateItemWriter.write(list);
        hibernateItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
}
```

I will be getting the complete the single CSV file to be processed and I don't want to split the CSV, so I will be using the same Reader process to read the CSV records. However I want to introduce multiple Processor & Writer **to improve the performance**. something like **AsyncItemProcessor**

```
<bean id="student" class="com.mkyong.entity.Student" scope="prototype" />

<batch:job id="helloWorldJob">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk
                    reader="cvsFileItemReader"
                    processor="itemProcessor"
                    writer="itemWriter"
                commit-interval="10">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="cvsFileItemReader" class="com.mkyong.batch.Reader" />

<bean id="itemProcessor" class="com.mkyong.batch.Processor" />

<bean id="itemWriter" class="com.mkyong.batch.Writer" />
```

How do I convert this to support **AsyncItemProcessor**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before going async or parallel, you should first fix the code you shared. The `Reader` class is incorrect. It is currently declared to read items of type `FlatFileItemReader` and not `Student`. The `read` method should return items of type `Student` and not the reader itself. This class is not needed, you can use the `FlatFileItemReader` provided by Spring Batch directly in your step.

Same thing for the writer, you can use `HibernateItemWriter` directly in your step.

Now to answer your question about using an asynchronous processor and writer, you need to wrap your processor in a `AsyncItemProcessor` and your writer in a `AsyncItemWriter`. You can find more details and a code example here: [Asynchronous Processors](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#asynchronous-processors).

Comment: <bean id="itemProcessorAsync" class="org.springframework.batch.integration.async.AsyncItemProcessor">
  <property name="delegate" ref="itemProcessor"/>
  <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutorAsync" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="itemWriterAsync" class="org.springframework.batch.integration.async.AsyncItemWriter">
  <property name="delegate" ref="itemWriter"/>
 </bean>

this is what I found in one of the article, taskExecutor is set only for the processor but not for the writer, can I set the taskExecutor for writer to?

Comment: No, the writer does not require a task executor. It only unwraps the `Future`s returned by the item processor.